# Document is not defined using BrowserRouter from React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, next.js

I'm facing a small problem that is causing a 500 error. It occurs when I attempt to embed either my Main or Login component (depending on the authentication state) with the BrowserRouter from React Router DOM. This trace appears in my VSCode console every time I refresh the client:

```
⨯ node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.js (333:13) @ document
 ⨯ Internal error: ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at getUrlBasedHistory (./node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.js:342:29)
    at createBrowserHistory (./node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.js:211:12)
    at BrowserRouter (./node_modules/react-router-dom/dist/index.js:713:96)
    at as (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:6505)
    at /Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11284
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13038)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at av (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:7923)
    at /Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13014
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13038)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at av (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:7923)
    at /Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13014
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13038)
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:43088)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at aC (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:50165)
    at a_ (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49406)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46647)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:41727)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at av (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:7923)
    at /Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13014
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13038)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at al (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:7504)
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10920)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at av (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:7923)
    at /Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13014
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13038)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at al (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:7504)
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10920)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at av (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:7923)
    at /Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13014
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:13038)
    at e (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46298)
    at ak (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:48276)
    at aw (/Users/nacho/Documents/ReactProjects/VTTS/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:39511)
```

Layout.tsx:

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import { PrimeReactProvider } from "primereact/api";
import "./bootstrap-grid.min.css";
import "./bootstrap-utilities.min.css";
import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <PrimeReactProvider>
        <html lang="en">
          <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </html>
      </PrimeReactProvider>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Main page.tsx:

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSessionStore } from "./context/SessionStore";

import Main from "./components/Main";
import Login from "./components/Login";

export default function Home() {
  const { isAuth } = useSessionStore() as { isAuth: boolean };

  return <BrowserRouter>{isAuth ? <Main /> : <Login />}</BrowserRouter>;
}
```

Main.tsx

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import styles from "../page.module.css";
import Navbar from "./ui/Navbar";
import { Card } from "primereact/card";
import TestRelease from "./TestRelease";

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <Navbar />
      <div className={styles.description}>
        <p>You are logged&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <Card className="offset-lg-1 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10">
        <TestRelease />
      </Card>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Login.tsx:

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, FormEvent } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useSessionStore } from "../context/SessionStore";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import { Password } from "primereact/password";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
import { Card } from "primereact/card";

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleLogin = async (event: FormEvent) => {
    console.log(username, password);
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/getAuthToken", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.token) {
      const user = { username: data.user.user_name, assigned: data.user.assigned, mail_sign: data.user.mail_sign };
      window.localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
      useSessionStore.setState({ isAuth: true, role: data.user.role });
      router.push("/");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <Card className="text-center">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title text-center">Inicio de Sesión</h2>
              <form>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <span className="p-input-icon-left">
                    <i className="pi pi-user" />
                    <InputText placeholder="Login" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <span className="p-input-icon-left">
                    <i className="pi pi-unlock" />
                    <Password
                      placeholder="Password"
                      value={password}
                      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                      toggleMask
                      feedback={false}
                    />
                  </span>
                </div>
                <Button type="button" label="Login" onClick={handleLogin} />
              </form>
            </div>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I tried to the remove the  annotation and the 500 error disappears, but links on my nav bar are not working

There is obviously something that I am not understanding or doing incorrectly, as this is quite basic, but I am really stuck.

Thank you in advance.